# How to start OpenTok/TokBox session archive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, opentok, tokbox

I'm working on an app that allow users to make video calls. I'm doing this by using OpenTok2.5 iOS SDK. I want to record calls and want to store them somewhere. My problem is, there is no way to start a call archiving using Open Tok iOS SDK. I'm using parse for app backend support(database). Could someone please provide some example code or any tutorial to do this from app side or by using parse cloud code.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1):

The actual call to start archiving is made by your **server**. This is most likely going to be triggered by your client, but the distinction between starting the archive vs triggering it is important. I've listed the steps to explain this in more detail below:

1. Make a call from your client (in this case the iOS device) to your server to let it know that the user wants to start an archive. You should probably be using a POST request.
2. Once your server receives the request, it should make a call to start the archive. The OpenTok [Server Side SDK](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/server/) should include a convenience method called `opentok.startArchive()` that does this for you, but [under the hood, it's just a POST request](https://tokbox.com/opentok/api/#start_archive) to OpenTok servers.
3. Upon receiving the response from the OpenTok server, your server should send back the appropriate response to your client (for the request in step 1).
4. Upon receiving the response on your client, perform any necessary application specific logic that you need.